# Error meta-data with ARCore in AndroidStudio

Tags: android, android-manifest, arcore

I try to follow this guide for ARCore in Android Studio  : https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/enable-arcore#manifest

I follow the steps but when I try to check if ARCore is supported on the device i have an error :

```
E/ARCore-ArCoreApk: Error while checking app details and ARCore status
com.google.ar.core.exceptions.FatalException: Application manifest must contain meta-data com.google.ar.core.min_apk_version
    at com.google.ar.core.k.e(ArCoreApkImpl.java:41)
    at com.google.ar.core.k.b(ArCoreApkImpl.java:52)
    at com.google.ar.core.k.checkAvailability(ArCoreApkImpl.java:5)
```

I don't understand why i should specify the min apk version in the manifest.
I have it in the build.gradle(:app) :

```
minSdkVersion 21
```

In the dependencies I have :

```
    implementation 'com.google.ar:core:1.18.0'
```

In the repositories I have :

```
    repositories {
    google()
```

In the manifest I have :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="XXXXX">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="Test"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    tools:node="replace"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <meta-data android:name="com.google.ar.core" android:value="optional" />


    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
    </provider>

    <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
        tools:ignore="LockedOrientationActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

In the class :

```
    public void Check_AR()
{
    ArCoreApk.Availability availability = ArCoreApk.getInstance().checkAvailability(getApplicationContext());
    if (availability.isTransient())
    {
        // Re-query at 5Hz while compatibility is checked in the background.
        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                Check_AR();
            }
        }, 200);
    }
    if (availability.isSupported())
    {
        Flag_AR = true;
    }
    else
    { // Unsupported or unknown.
        Flag_AR = false;
    }
    Log.d("TAG", "Check_AR: " + Flag_AR);
}
```

Can anybody help me ?
Thank you in advance !

EDIT :
When i analyse APK in android studio, I can see that the uses-sdk is here and match the graddle.
But I have an error on
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
--> URI is not registred (Settings | Languages & FrameWorks | Schemas and DTDs)
Can this be related ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer.
Just replace :

```
 tools:node="replace"
```

by

```
tools:node="merge"
```

In the manifest.

Answer (score 0):

`Application manifest` can refer to both the `build.gradle` declaration or a definition in an android manifest (https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/versioning#appversioning):

> Note: If your app defines the app version directly in the  element, the version values in the Gradle build file will override the settings in the manifest. Additionally, defining these settings in the Gradle build files allows you to specify different values for different versions of your app. For greater flexibility and to avoid potential overwriting when the manifest is merged, you should remove these attributes from the  element and define your version settings in the Gradle build files instead.

It looks like ARCore can't find the metadata in your APK. It's possible that the minSdkVersion is placed in the wrong place; it's hard to tell without the entire build file.

You can use [Android Studio's APK Analyzer](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/apk-analyzer) to find out which metadata is present in your generated `AndroidManifest.xml`.